# Adding New file Extensions in Dreamweaver CC 2018

Tags: dreamweaver, file-extension

I'm trying to add a new extension to a new site I'm creating in Dreamweaver CC 2018.

I can't figure out how to add the new file extension I am wanting.

I searched the support system for Adobe, but it only has certain file extensions as examples -- it doesn't provide a list of non-compatible extensions (only some that are for sure compatible).

Do you know if there is a list or have you experienced certain file extensions that cannot be incorporated into Dreamweaver?

Answer (score -1):

I used the steps here and it worked for me:
http://www.andrewnoske.com/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver_-_adding_new_extensions_and_syntax_highlighting

These are the steps involved

- Adding a New File Extension to Dreamweaver's Recognized Extensions (Extensions.txt)
- Mapping a File Extension to (MMDocumentTypes.xml)
- Creating a new Syntax Color Scheme (CodeColoring.xml)
- Creating a new Syntax Color Scheme (Colors.xml)